# Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) in filezilla

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, ssh-keys, filezilla

when i try to use filezilla to connect to  Instances in aws i got this error:
Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Comment: I had not to answer :(

Answer (score -1):

Have you set the private key in Filezilla? Since the EC2 is projected by ssh key, you have to attach the key when you connect through ssh or ftp. Go to the settings of Filezilla and find the tab, *sftp*. Then, you can add the private key to the Filezilla. After that, it would work.